# When using Vagrant up, the password is always entered incorrectly

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, virtualbox

When using Vagrant up, the password is always entered incorrectly,my Vagrantfile file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "k8s-ctl" do |c|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    config.ssh.username = "myhtls"
    config.ssh.password = "123456"
    config.ssh.insert_key = false
    c.vm.network "public_network"
    end

  config.vm.define "k8s-master" do |c|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    config.ssh.username = "myhtls"
    config.ssh.password = "123456"
    config.ssh.insert_key = false
    c.vm.network "public_network"
    end

end
```

In doc, enter the command vagrant up:

```
Bringing machine 'k8s-ctl' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

Bringing machine 'k8s-master' up with 'virtualbox' provider...

==> k8s-ctl: Importing base box 'ubuntu/xenial64'...

==> k8s-ctl: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...

==> k8s-ctl: Checking if box 'ubuntu/xenial64' is up to date...

==> k8s-ctl: Setting the name of the VM: deploy_k8s-ctl_1505998038511_39277



    k8s-ctl: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222

    k8s-ctl: SSH username: myhtls

    k8s-ctl: SSH auth method: password



myhtls@127.0.0.1's password:
```

I enter the password 123456, has been unable to let me through, what is the reason?

What is the reason why can not pass the password, ask how to solve this problem.

Comment: did you create those user in the VM ? if not you should not assume they exist

Comment: Not created, how to create?

Comment: search for 'create user in ubuntu' in google

Comment: First to enter ubuntu after the creation of users? But now I can not get there now

Comment: so remove `config.ssh.username` and `config.ssh.password` - vagrant will automatically connect with the default user

Comment: Use the default time, do not know what the password is. If the default password is vagrant landing is not into the

Comment: Have you tried the box with a simple default configuration? Like here: https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/xenial64

Answer (score 0):

The password in /Users/myhtls/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-xenial64/20170919.0.0/virtualbox/Vagrantfile is logged in from the virtual machine to ubuntu. And then add the vagrant user and password, you can log through the doc